# Fill vector with true value

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std, stdvector

i would like to make all the values in a `std::vector` `true`. I wrote 2 methods: the first one worked but the second did not. It tells me myproj.exe has triggered a breakpoint. Do you know what is the problem?

This one works:

```cpp
void first(std::vector<bool>& vect, unsigned int n) 
{       
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {       
        vect.push_back(true);
    }
}
```

This one does not:

```cpp
void secound(std::vector<bool>& vect, unsigned int n) 
{       
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        vect[i] = true; //crash here        
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `std::vector<bool>` is a bit weird. It does not behave like all the other `std::vector` specializations. You might be better of using something else depending on your use case.

Comment: In fact `vector<bool>` is so weird that it [gets its own documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) to explain just how weird.

Comment: @user4581301 why is it weird? IMHO it just follows the strategy to optimize wherever possible while keeping the interface?

Comment: @JoachimLusiardi It behaves in a manner that is unlike all of the other containers. That is weird.

Answer (score 6):

In *first* case you call `push_back` which automatically increases size of vector.

In *second* case you trying to access `vect[i]` which does not exist as size of vector is 0.

Easiest way to fill vector here would be

```
vect = std::vector<bool>(n, true);
```

Comment: Worth noting that the function is redundant. The same constructor used here, `std::vector<bool>(n, true);`, can be applied to the argument `vector` when it is created. In other words `std::vector<bool> my_vector(n, true);` eliminates the need to pass `my_vector` into either filling function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)'s overload:

```cpp
vector(size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

where the first argument is the size of the `std::vector` and the second argument is the initial value.

Full code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<bool> v(10, true);

    for (auto i : v) {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << i << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`std::vector<bool> v(10, true);` will create a vector with 10 boolean `true` values.

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:'%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::vector%3Cbool%3E+v(10,+true)%3B%0A%0A++++for+(auto+i+:+v)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+std::boolalpha+%3C%3C+i+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.85494633014216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

If you want to reinitialize the `std::vector`, these are the following options:

1. use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) like this `std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), true);`
2. use [`std::vector::resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) like this `v.resize(10, true);` if the `std::vector` is already initialized
3. use [`std::vector::assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) like this `v.assign(10, true);`

Comment: Thank you but this is not the answer to my question.

Comment: @cain It is the answer to your headline, and your implementation is inferior.

Comment: oh ok you are right. sorry , but why is my implementation inferior?

Comment: @cain because there is no need for the function at all. NutCracker has demonstrated 4 ways the `vector` can fill itself with a repeated value without any outside assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the second function implementation is that if the vector is empty or there are less elements than the value of the second parameter then you may not use the subscript operator. Otherwise you have undefined behavior.

Also there is a logical difference between the implementations.

In the first function implementation new elements are appended to already existent elements of the vector. In the second function implementation existent elements are overwritten.

But in any case the both function implementations look not good. You could do the same operation using one method of the class std::vector.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

void reset( std::vector<bool> &v, size_t n, bool value = false )
{
    v.assign( n, value );
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<bool> v;

    reset( v, 5);

    for ( const auto item : v )
    {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    reset( v, 5, true );

    for ( const auto item : v )
    {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
false false false false false 
true true true true true
```

Comment: Kind of pointless to replicate `.assign` as `reset`, though. Could as well call `.assign` directly where `reset` is called.

Comment: @walnut I can not agree. It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [std::fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) to do this. This is more idiomatic c++ than reassignment

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> v(8);

    std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), true);
}
```